# trying to understand: import React, {component} from 'React';

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, components

I am working on how to have React.js work with a backend.  I have seen this syntax:

import React, {component} from 'React';

Why is {component} listed there?  In my mind, you would of course want to use components.  So I don't know why {component} is there.

I would think import React from 'React' would be enough... meaning "give me all of React".  But obviously I am missing some sort of concept here.

Thank you.

Comment: not the same.i am asking why React and {Component} are both being imported from React, instead of simply importing React. It is a similar question to the one you are referencing.  But it is a different question, and the difference is important.

Answer (score 3):

`React` is the default export from the `react` package, whereas `Component` is a named export in that package. You can either do

```
import React from 'react';

class MyClass extends React.Component { ... }
```

or

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyClass extends Component { ... }
```

Read more about JavaScript exports [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

**EDIT:** Actually, React uses a different pattern called exposing an API on the default export, which has the same import convention as named exports - you can look at their source [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/React.js)

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was also confused why the code was saying extends Component rather than extends React.Component.  So this actually clarifies both things that were confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of this:
`class MyComponent extends Component {}`.
`class MyComponent extends React.Component {}`

In each case, you need `Import React from 'react'` :)

Comment: I mean, in each case, you need `Import React from 'react'` but if you dont import `{component}`, you must write `extends React.Component`