# Importing component only in class not in function

Tags: reactjs

I’m bit confused Why we need to import component while creating class in react  ? Why we can’t import react  simply like we do in function component?

Comment: Because the component class extends react.Component and that's how importing works in JS. You *can* just import "react" and extend React.Component.

Comment: Functional components are created differently (or at least were; haven't looked in awhile) and need React, but nothing else, either because any other React things are accessed off React (like React.Component) or simply don't need it.

Comment: @Siid sharma did you get a chance to go through my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

**A functional component is just a plain JavaScript function which accepts props as an argument and returns a React element. A class component requires you to extend from React. Component and create a render function which returns a React element.**

To get detailed information about Functional vs Class Based Components you can go through this [article](https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108#:~:text=The%20most%20obvious%20one%20difference,which%20returns%20a%20React%20element.)

**React is popular because of its concept of Reusable web components**

While creating functional components we are writing a function, returning JSX that we want this component to represent. Then in the `ReactDOM.render()` we have an 
instance of functional components, wrapping it in JSX tags, which is a self closing component

Function return ui that we want to represent on the page, but
functional component cant do everything that we needed to do implement for eg. state and lifecycle methods

**Functional components are also called stateless components, because we could not do all the complex things with it like life cycle methods**

**Class Based Components**

The syntax of class is same as ES6

For class-based components we are using prototype system in Javascript and its setting up prototype with `React.Component`, that provide bunch of goodies for our `React.Component`

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from "react"

class App extends Component {
    constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
    name:"Bhavya",
    age: 20
    }
    }
    render(){
    return(
    <div>
    <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
    <h3>{this.state.age} years old</h3>
    </div>
    )
    }
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from "./App"

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**The above code of `App.js` can be written like this also:**

**App.js**

```
import React  from "react"                  ----> Take note of these two lines

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
    name:"Bhavya",
    age: 20
    }
    }
    render(){
    return(
    <div>
    <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
    <h3>{this.state.age} years old</h3>
    </div>
    )
    }
}

export default App;
```

**In the above example App class extends Components, so React undersatnds that this class is a component, and it renders(returns) a React Element.. So a React class Components is an ES6 class, will be a component once it 'extends'
 React component**  See [this](https://codeburst.io/react-js-understanding-functional-class-components-e65d723e909)

To know more about when to use functional OR Class based components refer this [SO ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097965/when-to-use-es6-class-based-react-components-vs-functional-es6-react-components)

**React is the default export from the react package, whereas Component is a named export in that package.** See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50653185/10348758)

To know why do you `import React` in functional components refer this [blog](https://medium.com/@Zwenza/why-do-you-need-to-import-react-in-functional-components-7385e4329ffb#:~:text=The%20reason%20is%20much%20more,the%20createElement%20call%20will%20fail.)

Comment: @Siid sharma did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you and if it's helpful, please dont forget to upvote and accept :)

Comment: Is this possible to use class component without extending component

Comment: @Siid sharma if you just want to write some HTML code in your js file then you can simply ```import react```, but if you want to use lifecycle methods, then you will have to extend default Component class. You can even go through this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/five-ways-to-convert-react-class-components-to-functional-components-with-react-hooks to convert class component to functional components

Comment: @Siid sharma To know more about React.Component you can even refer this https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: @Siid sharma  hope I answered your question, let me know if you need more info –